# How to programmatically resize a view in MFC?

Tags: mfc, resize

To my surprise, I can't easily find a solution. I want to set initial size of a view in MFC. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't size a view, but you can size the view's parent frame window:

```
GetParentFrame()->MoveWindow(x, y, width, height);
```